# Split a column with different delimeters

Tags: python, pandas, split

Hi I have a csv dataframe in python pandas that has a column that consists of three columns. Those columns are seperated with ',' but there is a column in my dataframe that has values that looks like this:

```
10Bet\t\t 7.50\t5.25\t 1.34 12BET\t\t 6.90\t 4.60\t 1.38 188BET\t\t 6.00\t 5.20\t 1.38 1xBet\t\t 8.30\t 5.75\t 1.32 888sport\t\t 7.50\t 5.10\t 1.33 bet-at-home\t\t 6.64\t 5.06\t 1.35 bet365\t\t 7.50\t 5.00\t 1.36 Betclic\t\t7.50\t 4.80\t1.35 Betfair\t\t 7.50\t 4.80\t 1.36 Betsafe\t\t 7.60\t 5.25\t 1.35 Betsson\t\t 7.60\t 5.25\t 1.35 BetVictor\t\t 8.00\t 5.25\t 1.33 Betway\t\t 6.50\t 5.25\t 1.36 bwin\t\t 7.25\t 5.00\t 1.35 ComeOn\t\t 7.50\t5.25\t 1.34 Expekt\t\t7.50\t 4.80\t1.35 Interwetten\t\t8.00\t 5.30\t1.30 mybet\t\t 7.50\t 5.00\t1.35 Pinnacle\t\t 8.33 \t 5.79 \t 1.36 SBOBET\t\t 7.40\t 4.80\t 1.35 Sportingbet\t\t 7.50\t5.20\t 1.36 Tipico\t\t8.00\t 5.30\t 1.35 Unibet\t\t 7.50\t 5.10\t 1.34 William Hill\t\t 6.00\t 4.80\t 1.40 youwin\t\t 7.50\t 5.20\t 1.36 Betfair Exchange\t\t 8.41\t 5.56\t 1.37
```

I want to split it on tabs but there are different number of tabs that separate the values in the cell, the types are;

```
'\t','\t\t ' there is a space in the two tab seperator.
```

I have tried to split it by `df['column'].apply(lambda x: x.split(\t))` but it popped out the error of `'float' object has no attribute 'split'`.

What I want to have is columns that are splitted on the delimiters `'\t'` or `'\t\t '`

How can I split this column so that it is shown like this in pandas or any other library in python?:

```
10Bet 7.50 5.25 1.34 12BET 6.90 4.60 1.38 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `\t+` - one or more tabs:

```
a = df['column'].str.split('\t+')
print (a)
0    [10Bet,  7.50, 5.25,  1.34 12BET,  6.90,  4.60...
Name: column, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael . This does help my case but with the example above it doesn't put a comma between 1.34 and 12BET and so on. I need to seperate them also.

Comment: It does not split because there is no tab, but whitespace. But if need split by whitespace - one or more use `a = df['column'].str.split('\s+')`

Comment: Thank you so much.